# How Do I use typescript declarations (.ts.d files) to consume a third party javascript API / SDK in an angular cli application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dropbox-api

I wanted to use the Dropbox API which is a javascript API in my angular cli project. The API ships with Typescript definitions. Here's what the dist folder looks like.
[image]

They have a sample function that returns a list of files written in a `.ts` file and a `.js` file:
Here's `basic.js` and `basic.ts` which returns a list of files:
`basic.js`:
[image]

and `basic.ts`:
[image]
Here is the html file the scripts are operating upon for reference:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dropbox TypeScript SDK</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <script src="/__build__/Dropbox-sdk.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Example layout boilerplate -->
  <header class="page-header">
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <a href="/">
          <h1>
            <img src="https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/brand/logotype_white-vflRG5Zd8.svg" class="logo" />
            TypeScript SDK Examples
          </h1>
        </a>
        <a href="https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/tree/master/examples/typescript" class="view-source">View Source</a>
      </nav>
      <h2 class="code">
        <a href="/">examples</a> / basic
      </h2>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Example description and UI -->
  <section class="container main">
    <p>This example fetches the contents of your root Dropbox directory. It uses the <code>Dropbox.filesListFolder()</code> method [<a href="http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesListFolder">docs</a>].</p>

    <form onSubmit="return listFiles()">
      <input type="text" id="access-token" placeholder="Access token" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <!-- The files returned from the SDK will be added here -->
    <ul id="files"></ul>

    <p class="info">To obtain an access token for quick testing, you can go to <a href="https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_list_folder" target="_blank">API Explorer</a> click the "Get Token" button on the top right, copy the token it creates and then paste it here.</p>
  </section>

  <!-- Scripts to run example -->
  <script src="basic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I use this API? I installed the npm but how do I use the `.d.ts` files? Should I use the `.ts` or `.js` code for my angular project? I want to use the api in one of my typescript components? I don't know how to include definitions and use those definitions in my angular components. I assume I include `Dropbox-sdk.min.js` is my scripts in `angular-cli.json` but where or how do I include the `.d.ts` files and which ones are necessary? I found no relevant documentation on the dropbox github. The github contains the full working examples for typescript and javascript use but it's a confusing project since it seems to mix many different things into the project and I don't know how to translate it for an angular-cli app https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js
If there's something else I should include in the question let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say you should just be able to import them like any other angular interface at the top, then reference them in your component, but looking on their repo how they generate their types it looks a little odd. Almost like they are declaring modules that dynamically build types using a generator. I know nothing about that. You could always try removing the module wrapper around this Dropbox class  -  https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/generator/typescript/dropbox.d.ts

and then adding 'export' before the Dropbox class definition on the second line?

Here it is like that stripped of all the comments.

EDIT - looks like you'll need to do the same with this file, the base class and interface. https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/edit/master/generator/typescript/dropbox_types.d.ts   export both the interface and class and remove the module lines.

Then you should be able to create an index.ts file that exports all of the statements from both files.

I feel like this is not the right way....but I dont see why it wont work.

```
export class Dropbox extends DropboxBase {

constructor(options: DropboxOptions);


public authTokenFromOauth1(arg: auth.TokenFromOAuth1Arg): Promise<auth.TokenFromOAuth1Result>;

public authTokenRevoke(arg: void): Promise<void>;

public filesAlphaGetMetadata(arg: files.AlphaGetMetadataArg): Promise<files.FileMetadataReference|files.FolderMetadataReference|files.DeletedMetadataReference>;

public filesAlphaUpload(arg: files.CommitInfoWithProperties): Promise<files.FileMetadata>;

public filesCopy(arg: files.RelocationArg): Promise<files.FileMetadataReference|files.FolderMetadataReference|files.DeletedMetadataReference>;

public filesCopyBatch(arg: files.RelocationBatchArg): Promise<files.RelocationBatchLaunch>;


public filesCopyBatchCheck(arg: async.PollArg): Promise<files.RelocationBatchJobStatus>;


public filesCopyReferenceGet(arg: files.GetCopyReferenceArg): Promise<files.GetCopyReferenceResult>;

public filesCopyReferenceSave(arg: files.SaveCopyReferenceArg): Promise<files.SaveCopyReferenceResult>;


public filesCopyV2(arg: files.RelocationArg): Promise<files.RelocationResult>;


public filesCreateFolder(arg: files.CreateFolderArg): Promise<files.FolderMetadata>;

public filesCreateFolderV2(arg: files.CreateFolderArg): Promise<files.CreateFolderResult>;


public filesDelete(arg: files.DeleteArg): Promise<files.FileMetadataReference|files.FolderMetadataReference|files.DeletedMetadataReference>;

public filesDeleteBatch(arg: files.DeleteBatchArg): Promise<files.DeleteBatchLaunch>;

public filesDeleteBatchCheck(arg: async.PollArg): Promise<files.DeleteBatchJobStatus>;

public filesDeleteV2(arg: files.DeleteArg): Promise<files.DeleteResult>;

public filesDownload(arg: files.DownloadArg): Promise<files.FileMetadata>;

public filesGetMetadata(arg: files.GetMetadataArg): Promise<files.FileMetadataReference|files.FolderMetadataReference|files.DeletedMetadataReference>;

public filesGetPreview(arg: files.PreviewArg): Promise<files.FileMetadata>;

public filesGetTemporaryLink(arg: files.GetTemporaryLinkArg): Promise<files.GetTemporaryLinkResult>;

public filesGetThumbnail(arg: files.ThumbnailArg): Promise<files.FileMetadata>;

public filesListFolder(arg: files.ListFolderArg): Promise<files.ListFolderResult>;

public filesListFolderContinue(arg: files.ListFolderContinueArg): Promise<files.ListFolderResult>;

public filesListFolderGetLatestCursor(arg: files.ListFolderArg): Promise<files.ListFolderGetLatestCursorResult>;

public filesListFolderLongpoll(arg: files.ListFolderLongpollArg): Promise<files.ListFolderLongpollResult>;

public filesListRevisions(arg: files.ListRevisionsArg): Promise<files.ListRevisionsResult>;

public filesMove(arg: files.RelocationArg): Promise<files.FileMetadataReference|files.FolderMetadataReference|files.DeletedMetadataReference>;

public filesMoveBatch(arg: files.RelocationBatchArg): Promise<files.RelocationBatchLaunch>;

public filesMoveBatchCheck(arg: async.PollArg): Promise<files.RelocationBatchJobStatus>;

public filesMoveV2(arg: files.RelocationArg): Promise<files.RelocationResult>;

public filesPermanentlyDelete(arg: files.DeleteArg): Promise<void>;

public filesPropertiesAdd(arg: files.PropertyGroupWithPath): Promise<void>;

public filesPropertiesOverwrite(arg: files.PropertyGroupWithPath): Promise<void>;

public filesPropertiesRemove(arg: files.RemovePropertiesArg): Promise<void>;

public filesPropertiesTemplateGet(arg: properties.GetPropertyTemplateArg): Promise<properties.GetPropertyTemplateResult>;

public filesPropertiesTemplateList(arg: void): Promise<properties.ListPropertyTemplateIds>;

public filesPropertiesUpdate(arg: files.UpdatePropertyGroupArg): Promise<void>;

public filesRestore(arg: files.RestoreArg): Promise<files.FileMetadata>;

public filesSaveUrl(arg: files.SaveUrlArg): Promise<files.SaveUrlResult>;

public filesSaveUrlCheckJobStatus(arg: async.PollArg): Promise<files.SaveUrlJobStatus>;

public filesSearch(arg: files.SearchArg): Promise<files.SearchResult>;

public filesUpload(arg: files.CommitInfo): Promise<files.FileMetadata>;

public filesUploadSessionAppend(arg: files.UploadSessionCursor): Promise<void>;

public filesUploadSessionAppendV2(arg: files.UploadSessionAppendArg): Promise<void>;

public filesUploadSessionFinish(arg: files.UploadSessionFinishArg): Promise<files.FileMetadata>;

public filesUploadSessionFinishBatch(arg: files.UploadSessionFinishBatchArg): Promise<files.UploadSessionFinishBatchLaunch>;

public filesUploadSessionFinishBatchCheck(arg: async.PollArg): Promise<files.UploadSessionFinishBatchJobStatus>;

public filesUploadSessionStart(arg: files.UploadSessionStartArg): Promise<files.UploadSessionStartResult>;

public paperDocsArchive(arg: paper.RefPaperDoc): Promise<void>;

public paperDocsDownload(arg: paper.PaperDocExport): Promise<paper.PaperDocExportResult>;

public paperDocsFolderUsersList(arg: paper.ListUsersOnFolderArgs): Promise<paper.ListUsersOnFolderResponse>;

public paperDocsFolderUsersListContinue(arg: paper.ListUsersOnFolderContinueArgs): Promise<paper.ListUsersOnFolderResponse>;

public paperDocsGetFolderInfo(arg: paper.RefPaperDoc): Promise<paper.FoldersContainingPaperDoc>;

public paperDocsList(arg: paper.ListPaperDocsArgs): Promise<paper.ListPaperDocsResponse>;

public paperDocsListContinue(arg: paper.ListPaperDocsContinueArgs): Promise<paper.ListPaperDocsResponse>;

public paperDocsPermanentlyDelete(arg: paper.RefPaperDoc): Promise<void>;

public paperDocsSharingPolicyGet(arg: paper.RefPaperDoc): Promise<paper.SharingPolicy>;

public paperDocsSharingPolicySet(arg: paper.PaperDocSharingPolicy): Promise<void>;

public paperDocsUsersAdd(arg: paper.AddPaperDocUser): Promise<Array<paper.AddPaperDocUserMemberResult>>;

public paperDocsUsersList(arg: paper.ListUsersOnPaperDocArgs): Promise<paper.ListUsersOnPaperDocResponse>;

public paperDocsUsersListContinue(arg: paper.ListUsersOnPaperDocContinueArgs): Promise<paper.ListUsersOnPaperDocResponse>;

public paperDocsUsersRemove(arg: paper.RemovePaperDocUser): Promise<void>;

public sharingAddFileMember(arg: sharing.AddFileMemberArgs): Promise<Array<sharing.FileMemberActionResult>>;

public sharingAddFolderMember(arg: sharing.AddFolderMemberArg): Promise<void>;

public sharingChangeFileMemberAccess(arg: sharing.ChangeFileMemberAccessArgs): Promise<sharing.FileMemberActionResult>;

public sharingCheckJobStatus(arg: async.PollArg): Promise<sharing.JobStatus>;

public sharingCheckRemoveMemberJobStatus(arg: async.PollArg): Promise<sharing.RemoveMemberJobStatus>;

public sharingCheckShareJobStatus(arg: async.PollArg): Promise<sharing.ShareFolderJobStatus>;

public sharingCreateSharedLink(arg: sharing.CreateSharedLinkArg): Promise<sharing.PathLinkMetadata>;

public sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings(arg: sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsArg): Promise<sharing.FileLinkMetadataReference|sharing.FolderLinkMetadataReference|sharing.SharedLinkMetadataReference>;

public sharingGetFileMetadata(arg: sharing.GetFileMetadataArg): Promise<sharing.SharedFileMetadata>;

public sharingGetFileMetadataBatch(arg: sharing.GetFileMetadataBatchArg): Promise<Array<sharing.GetFileMetadataBatchResult>>;

public sharingGetFolderMetadata(arg: sharing.GetMetadataArgs): Promise<sharing.SharedFolderMetadata>;

public sharingGetSharedLinkFile(arg: sharing.GetSharedLinkFileArg): Promise<sharing.FileLinkMetadataReference|sharing.FolderLinkMetadataReference|sharing.SharedLinkMetadataReference>;

public sharingGetSharedLinkMetadata(arg: sharing.GetSharedLinkMetadataArg): Promise<sharing.FileLinkMetadataReference|sharing.FolderLinkMetadataReference|sharing.SharedLinkMetadataReference>;

public sharingGetSharedLinks(arg: sharing.GetSharedLinksArg): Promise<sharing.GetSharedLinksResult>;

public sharingListFileMembers(arg: sharing.ListFileMembersArg): Promise<sharing.SharedFileMembers>;

public sharingListFileMembersBatch(arg: sharing.ListFileMembersBatchArg): Promise<Array<sharing.ListFileMembersBatchResult>>;

public sharingListFileMembersContinue(arg: sharing.ListFileMembersContinueArg): Promise<sharing.SharedFileMembers>;

public sharingListFolderMembers(arg: sharing.ListFolderMembersArgs): Promise<sharing.SharedFolderMembers>;

public sharingListFolderMembersContinue(arg: sharing.ListFolderMembersContinueArg): Promise<sharing.SharedFolderMembers>;

public sharingListFolders(arg: sharing.ListFoldersArgs): Promise<sharing.ListFoldersResult>;

public sharingListFoldersContinue(arg: sharing.ListFoldersContinueArg): Promise<sharing.ListFoldersResult>;

public sharingListMountableFolders(arg: sharing.ListFoldersArgs): Promise<sharing.ListFoldersResult>;

public sharingListMountableFoldersContinue(arg: sharing.ListFoldersContinueArg): Promise<sharing.ListFoldersResult>;

public sharingListReceivedFiles(arg: sharing.ListFilesArg): Promise<sharing.ListFilesResult>;

public sharingListReceivedFilesContinue(arg: sharing.ListFilesContinueArg): Promise<sharing.ListFilesResult>;

public sharingListSharedLinks(arg: sharing.ListSharedLinksArg): Promise<sharing.ListSharedLinksResult>;

public sharingModifySharedLinkSettings(arg: sharing.ModifySharedLinkSettingsArgs): Promise<sharing.FileLinkMetadataReference|sharing.FolderLinkMetadataReference|sharing.SharedLinkMetadataReference>;

public sharingMountFolder(arg: sharing.MountFolderArg): Promise<sharing.SharedFolderMetadata>;

public sharingRelinquishFileMembership(arg: sharing.RelinquishFileMembershipArg): Promise<void>;

public sharingRelinquishFolderMembership(arg: sharing.RelinquishFolderMembershipArg): Promise<async.LaunchEmptyResult>;

public sharingRemoveFileMember(arg: sharing.RemoveFileMemberArg): Promise<sharing.FileMemberActionIndividualResult>;

public sharingRemoveFileMember2(arg: sharing.RemoveFileMemberArg): Promise<sharing.FileMemberRemoveActionResult>;

public sharingRemoveFolderMember(arg: sharing.RemoveFolderMemberArg): Promise<async.LaunchResultBase>;

public sharingRevokeSharedLink(arg: sharing.RevokeSharedLinkArg): Promise<void>;

public sharingShareFolder(arg: sharing.ShareFolderArg): Promise<sharing.ShareFolderLaunch>;

public sharingTransferFolder(arg: sharing.TransferFolderArg): Promise<void>;

public sharingUnmountFolder(arg: sharing.UnmountFolderArg): Promise<void>;

public sharingUnshareFile(arg: sharing.UnshareFileArg): Promise<void>;

public sharingUnshareFolder(arg: sharing.UnshareFolderArg): Promise<async.LaunchEmptyResult>;

public sharingUpdateFileMember(arg: sharing.UpdateFileMemberArgs): Promise<sharing.MemberAccessLevelResult>;

public sharingUpdateFolderMember(arg: sharing.UpdateFolderMemberArg): Promise<sharing.MemberAccessLevelResult>;

public sharingUpdateFolderPolicy(arg: sharing.UpdateFolderPolicyArg): Promise<sharing.SharedFolderMetadata>;

public teamLogGetEvents(arg: team_log.GetTeamEventsArg): Promise<team_log.GetTeamEventsResult>;

public teamLogGetEventsContinue(arg: team_log.GetTeamEventsContinueArg): Promise<team_log.GetTeamEventsResult>;

public usersGetAccount(arg: users.GetAccountArg): Promise<users.BasicAccount>;

public usersGetAccountBatch(arg: users.GetAccountBatchArg): Promise<users.GetAccountBatchResult>;

public usersGetCurrentAccount(arg: void): Promise<users.FullAccount>;

public usersGetSpaceUsage(arg: void): Promise<users.SpaceUsage>;
}
```

Comment: So just to clarify, you'd suggest creating a d.ts (does the name matter?) file and pasting that code in to use the typescript example in my angular project? Do i have to import it into my component? If so, how is that done? Should something be added to the app.module.ts as well. Sorry I don't have any experience working with d.ts files.

Comment: the name shouldnt matter if you're manually importing it into the components / services that need it. You could call it dropbox.d.ts to keep it separate. But i do believe index.ts files have to be named as such to work as a typescript barrel, so maybe create a folder named dropbox with both files. As long as you remove the 'module' wrapper and convert the class declarations to 'export class' and 'export interface', i think it will work.

Comment: Do I register the class with app.module.ts? If so, where/how? Can you give an example of importing into a component as well?

Comment: So create 2 modified .d.ts files and an index.ts file? What should be contained in the index.ts file?

Comment: Here, I combined them all into a single file. It appears to be satisfying Typescript's type checking in VS Code. Maybe it will work.  


http://www.brocco.ly/assets/dropbox.d.ts

import into component like  

import { DropboxBase, Dropbox, ...maybe other things it warns you you might need... } from './assets/dropbox.d.ts'

you could put the file anywhere i suppose.

Comment: I dunno, I'm grasping for straws here.

Comment: Ok - i am going to edit my original answer. I got it to work. Updated the file.

Comment: As is it's not working for me. the imports work in vs code but when I try to run I get an error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../dropbox'

Comment: Yeah me neither. I got the types file to check out properly but the js isnt' reading it right. I dunno.  I know this isn't the "right" way to do it, I just was curious if it would work. But I also don't know what the right way is.